# How do i create a routine that would constantly run in the background?

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am making a primitive database in Excel and need a routine to run in the background constantly. I will be able to fill in the actual actions it needs to do, but I don't know how to make something run independent of a key press or some sort of Macro. If someone can give me an example of code that runs independently which I can simply fill with contents, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If your code were to run "constantly" in the background, it would cause Excel to become unresponsive. I don't this is actually what you want. Could you describe what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly.
I have a working interface which has a data stream coming in. What I need is something which will sample data from different cells on certain intervals. I guess a good clarification would be to say I need the process to happen independently of any user input, it should just kind of supervise constantly and do it's thing regardless of all else.

Answer (score 3):

Try this http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/run-macro-on-time.htm

Comment: @Jerome: make sure to accept the answer if it suits your needs, it'll help others with similar questions. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with VBA for quite some time now, but you would have to create a thread in VBA, maybe by COM-Threading, but I am not too sure if Excel is threadsafe or if you even can use Threads of some kind in Excel. Another alternative would be a Timer. If it is not implemented in VBA and I don't remember it to be, you would have to create the Timer yourself and react to the Windows Message yourself, if you can do that in VBA.

All in all I think this uses case might be to big for an Excel VBA Macro. If I were you I would consider doing this in a different way.